# Write JSON Object to file- append not working

Tags: java, android, json, file-io, streamwriter

I'try to save my custom JSONObject into the file.Everything working correct but I can't append json into file.For example,If I click twice to save json,in my file I have one element.Here is a my source

```
public class TransactionFileManager {
public static final File path = Environment.
        getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/myfolder/");
public static final File file = new File(path, "transaction1.json");

public static String read() {
    String ret = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        try {
            String receiveString;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}


public static void writeToFile(JSONObject data) {
    if (!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdirs();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        outputStreamWriter.append(data.toString());
        outputStreamWriter.close();
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

How I can append json object into my .json file.What's a wrong in my code
thanks

Comment: first you need to prepare full string like you click twise then create combined string then you need to write into file.

Comment: Please tell more about it @FalduJaldeep

Comment: you mean that I must combine string file each time and then put it in Database ,right ? is it a possible to combine without each time ?

Comment: Write operation will be last first you need to create string what ever you need to write into file...